# weblogic warnings reduces system performance

Tags: oracle, jsf, weblogic

I am developing a web application that runs on weblogic 10g, JSF, oracle database. When I enter a page that requires to get huge query results, I come across with the following warnings:

```
1  xyz-warPU  INFO   [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] openjpa.jdbc.JDBC - Using dictionary class "kodo.jdbc.sql.KodoOracleDictionary" (Oracle Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production ,Oracle JDBC driver 11.1.0.6.0-Production+).

112  xyz-warPU  INFO   [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] openjpa.Enhance - Creating subclass and redefining methods for "[class com.asd.xyz]". This means that your application will be less efficient than it would if you ran the OpenJPA enhancer.
```

While jumping through the pages my system gets very slow and the logs are being thrown continously.

My question is how to disable this logging feature to be able to access pages as desired?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out this page on how to configure your OpenJPA. It sounds like you might not be using the recommended settings: http://openjpa.apache.org/beginners-performance-guide.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the application server's logging level. From most to least logging it is:

```
TRACE, DEBUG, INFO, NOTICE, WARNING, ERROR, CRITICAL, ALERT, EMERGENCY
```

When developing an application you might use TRACE or DEBUG but in production it should probably be WARNING or higher.

Reference: [Configuring WebLogic Logging Services](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13739/config_logs.htm)

Comment: Thanks for comment, where should I change the logging level?

Comment: Lots of places in can be changed depending on what levels you want active where. The reference is a good start.